# What is the best way to generate an atom or rss feed in node.js application

Tags: json, node.js, rss, atom-feed

I'm trying to add newsfeeds to an node.js application using express.js and I can't find a painless way to take a json model and turn it into an atom or rss feed. Best solutions i've come up with is use an Xml library (also not so hot on node.js) or EJS template and build it up by hand.

There seems to be plenty of code for parsing rss/atom into json, but not for going the other direction. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Searching the NPM registery for RSS

gives [rss](https://github.com/dylang/node-rss)

See their [github page](https://github.com/dylang/node-rss) for more details.

As general advice, do search the npm registry for relevant keywords. It'll make your life easier.

Comment: Both of those are parsers, not generators

Comment: @ArneClaassen I realised and removed them. I replaced it with node-rss which is a generator.

Comment: Sweetness! That's precisely what i was looking for. thx! Ok, lesson for next time.. search npm, don't just trust google

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Feed for Node.js](http://projets.jpmonette.net/en/feed). It is a very simple wrapper that I created a couple of weeks ago to generate some Atom and RSS feed in no time.

Simply install it using NPM:

```
$ npm install feed
```

Then, follow the documentation available there http://projets.jpmonette.net/en/feed !

Comment: Note: link is broken.

Comment: Couldn't find docs :\ But the setup test is a good starting point! https://github.com/jpmonette/feed/blob/master/src/__tests__/setup.ts And execute `rss2()` method: https://github.com/jpmonette/feed/blob/master/src/__tests__/rss2.spec.ts

Comment: If you do not use typescript, you can use feed like so: `const Feed = require('feed').Feed;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not.  The best I can do is recommend you look at [wheat](http://thechangelog.com/post/526646366/wheat-blog-engine-for-node-js), a "complete blogging solution" written in Node.  It has a couple of feed supports, but they're mostly just template-driven hand-written XML things.

Or, you could write one and submit it to NPM!

Comment: I figure if i have to roll my own I might as well release back into the ecosystem. Was just hoping i wouldn't have to :)